# robocopy /copyall but not empty folders (/e)

Tags: batch-file, backup, robocopy

I'm looking to modify a robocopy script that is taking way too long to complete. The directory it is copying has thousand's of empty folders, which I'm told i cannot get rid of.

robocopy script switches are this:

```
robocopy /copyall /sec /mir /r:1 /w:1 /mt:24
```

The log file produces this:

```
robocopy /S /E /COPY:DATS /PURGE /MIR /MT:24 /R:1 /W:1
```

I think it will improve the time it takes to backup this directory if T can remove the /e switch. I assume this comes from `/copyall`.

Question is how can I still use `/copyall` but remove the `/e`? Is it as simple as manually adding the below switches, and removing `/e`? Or is there a better way?

```
/S /COPY:DATS /PURGE /MIR /MT:24 /R:1 /W:1
```

Below are the results from yesterday. Going from a file/print server to a NAS box across a 10GB link.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :    188548        35    188513         0         0         0
   Files :   1144788      1633   1143155         0         0        26
   Bytes : 397.981 g   1.033 g 396.948 g         0         0    7.88 m
   Times :   0:57:10   0:00:44                       0:00:00   0:56:18


   Speed :            29329947 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            1678.273 MegaBytes/min.
```

Comment: What is the magnitude of your entire copy?  An hour? More? How many GB would be transferred in the process? Have you calculated the transfer speed to see what the average speed is? Copying many small files will take far longer than several large file because of the file creation overhead, and will take far longer over a network.  Creating empty folders is very quick on a local drive - or are you copying to a network drive?

Comment: Can you do the copy to a fast hard drive on a regular PC over the same network?  Then add 35 files totaling 1 GB and run the command again to update the backup.  The reason is to compare the time taken on a PC mounted HDD to the NAS unit in similar circumstances, to see if the NAS unit is a large bottleneck.  In any case Robocopy has to compare over a million files and over 180 thousand folders every time this runs - and that is a big task by itself.  The `/e` doesn't copy or create anything after the first run, when most of the mirror has already copied. Or test it on a local HDD for speed.

Comment: `robocopy /S /COPY:DATS /PURGE /MT:24 /R:1 /W:1` You can test this command which should ignore the empty folders (when it is run initially will be most effective as those empty folders will not be created) but the `/purge` switch to delete files/folders in the target that not longer exist in the source is a switch that will slow it down too.  Removing the `/purge` switch and testing it is worthwhile too. `robocopy /S /COPY:DATS /MT:24 /R:1 /W:1`

Answer (score 0):

```
robocopy /?
```

says

```
/S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
```

Comment: Is /copyall adding the /e, if so, how do i remove, conflict between /s and /e

Comment: `/mir` is creating a mirror backup including empty folders.